# What is the problem with my image source?

Tags: html, image, web-crawler, src

I am currently making a php crawler. All is fine except one thing. I save the link of some images from the crawled website and after that , I want to show them in a html img tag. But the problem is that the photo is not loading currently ( it shows something default) but when I copy the link and I am opening it in the browser, everything works perfect.

Example :

```
   working -> https://photo.yupoo.com/husky-reps/82912680/small.jpg



  not working -> <img alt="ecommerce" src="https://photo.yupoo.com/husky-reps/82912680/small.jpg" class="object-cover object-center w-full h-full block">
```

Default photo that appears on "not working" example :

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It's working fine in my end, please check if the other code has some issue

Comment: This is a `.gif` file. Remove class attribute and check what happens. I think it's due to the classes.

Comment: I don't understand. Which one is .gif  ?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the jpg file it redirects you (302) to the .gif file.

It must be checking the headers for [origin of the call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) . A simple protection against using their assets in websites other than theirs.

After calling the image with success on their website, The headers used are `referer` and maybe `sec-fetch-site`

Your only option is to save the image (using the right headers) and serve it from your server.

Comment: OK . Thank you. So I have to download the image to my disk. How I can see which are the "right headers"?

Comment: @ChiricaAndrei check the network on their wabsite and check the request headers in the image call.

Comment: @ChiricaAndrei PS: I'm avoiding giving you the values on purpose as per the guideline of stackoverflow. please dont ask for them from me, I already told you how to get them yourself.